# Is there any (simple) way to pass variable from Express to Vue.js?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, passport.js, vuejs2

Ok, so I'm just starting to learn Vue.js, and man, it's so hard to do things that are very simple when just using EJS for example. I'm close to abandon Vue for my current project, since I just don't know how to pass `res.locals.something` from Express server to Vue frontend. By the way, it's Passport.js thing - when authenticated, user should be redirected, but I have to pass the info whether user has logged in or not to Vue (`res.locals.isLogged = req.isAuthenticated();`), and that seems impossible with my current (close to 0) Vue.js skills... The only solution I found was using ajax (axios was my choice) request on the client side, targeting `/login/facebook` route on the server, and then I could pass the response from Express to Vue, but it cannot work because of the damned CORS issue. So, I cannot use ajax to retrieve the data from Express, and Express and Vue are not natively connected like Express and EJS or Pug for example.

In short - does anyone know of a simple way to pass Express variable to Vue, not including Vue SSR, Express-vue module etc.?

P.S. I'm not using Webpack or anything similar (so, no .vue files etc.) - just a simple index.html file with Vue loaded from CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, one thing that crossed my mind as dirty workaround was using .ejs instead of .html extension, so I could pass the variable to ejs, but I thought it won't work. What I did was just renaming my index.html to index.ejs, passing res.locals.isLogged to ejs template and both Vue and ejs rendered parts of the app are working together, somehow...

So, this is the dirty (sort of) solution...

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered but I'm not familiar with `.ejs` and couldn't follow the solution. For those like me, what I did was :

1. Sent the `data` using `res.locals` or  `res.render('file.pug', data)`
2. Set the data received as a html data attribute to a tag ( ex : `p(id="myParagraph" data-myData= data)`
3. Set the state of the Vuex store using

```
mounted : function () {
  this.$store.state.myData = document.getElementById("myParagraph").getAttribute("data-myData");
}
```

The same can be used to set the `data` property of the vue root instance.

From here on you can use the data whenever needed and still retain reactivity.

Answer (score -2):

You're on the right track using `res.locals`. To get access to the variable in the JS that's in the view, you have to wrap the value in a string: `console.log('#{isLogged}')`. See example below

`app.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isLogged = false
  next()
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```

`views/index.pug`

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= text
  script.
    console.log('#{isLogged}') // false
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not using pug, I'm using plain HTML file with Vue.js rendering view. It is easy with pug, ejs etc.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. You have to wrap the value in quotes as shown above.

Comment: If I do that, I get only "[Vue warn]: Property or method "isLogged" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

(found in <Root>)". Console just logs the string "isLogged", not the value(false).

Comment: Ok, one thing that crossed my mind as dirty workaround was using .ejs instead of .html extension, so I could pass the variable to ejs, but I thought it won't work. What I did was just renaming my index.html to index.ejs, passing res.locals.isLogged to ejs template and both Vue and ejs rendered parts of the app are working together, somehow... If no one comes up with a better idea, I'm gonna mark this as an answer.